# JwtAuthenticationToken is not being saved to HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository after upgrading to 5.7 version

Tags: spring-security

Part of our application logic currently works like this:

1. First request being made with bearer JWT token to obtain html page for webview. User being authenticated, session being created, authentication being saved into the session.
2. All subsequent requests from that html page (static resources and ajax calls) being made without JWT (because we don't have it there), but within the same session that has been opened in the point above (with JSESSIONID cookie), so these requests being considered as authenticated by spring.

When upgrading to 5.7, the second part is not working anymore, and we're getting UNAUTHORIZED.

When investigating the issue, at some point I've realized that the problem is with security context not being saved into the repo anymore in `org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SaveToSessionResponseWrapper#saveContext`, because of this part of code:

```
final Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();   
if (isTransient(authentication)) {
      return;   
}
```

and our current authentication object, which is `org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken` marked with `@Transient` annotation.

Looks like the change was introduced by [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/70fa8b1fdbbf3fc2dd514f26d4a8285f24d5458b) here and related to [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9995) here.

Now, I know that this part of application logic/architecture is not perfect, still this is a little bit a breaking change for us :)

So my question is: is this should be considered as expected behavior and we should just change the logic/find a way to overcome this, or is this can be considered as a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: why are you mixing token based authentication with session based authentication into some homemade security solution? homemade security solutions are bad practice.

Comment: @Toerktumlare, totally agree with you, I'm not the one who made it like this in a first place :) But it worked prior to 5.7, so I'm wondering was this change intentional or this is some sort of side effect..